# How to debug web services deployed on tomcat on different machine?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I have a machine say 'M1' on which I have tomcat server instance created. I have deployed a war file on this server. This war contains all web services and other stuff. So from web side whenever I work in debug mode, I can't debug web services on browser debugger.

In my local machine I have eclipse installed which contain all codes. Using this I have created war file which is deployed on tomcat server on machine M1.

Is there any way by which I can debug web service calls from browser? Or is there any different way to debug web services which are deployed on remote machine?

Comment: Please give some comments before downflag. How would I know what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to add the following options when the JVM is started:

> -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n

This way you can debug the Tomcat server remotely.

For more info, see: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q1

Comment: hi...Thanks for your answer. Could you please remove answer? I want to delete this question.